# Unity C# Share Variable within Method with Other Script in Scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods

I'm developing a project in Unity in which I need to share a string variable (metaData_Content) between two scripts (script 1 & script 2) in the scene.  However, the variable that I need to share is not public or static, it is established within a method in script 1.  Because of this, I cannot get access to the variable from script 2.

Important Code in Script 1:

```
public class SimpleCloudHandler : MonoBehaviour, ICloudRecoEventHandler
{
    public void OnNewSearchResult(TargetFinder.TargetSearchResult targetSearchResult)
    {
        string metaData_Content = targetSearchResult.MetaData;
    }
}
```

Important Code in Script 2:

```
void alertPopUp(string metaData_Content){

    //

}
```

I have tried to use the GetComponent function(as shown below), but that only works if the string is public in script 1.

```
    GameObject cloudScript = GameObject.Find("CloudRecognition");
    SimpleCloudHandler simpleCloudHandler = cloudScript.GetComponent<SimpleCloudHandler> ();
    string metaData_Content = simpleCloudHandler.metaData_Content;
```

**Question:**

Is there some workaround that allows me to access the metaData_Content string from within script 2?

Comment: Make it a public variable? What am I missing here?

Comment: how about changing the return type of that method to a string and returning metaData_content?

Comment: Either make it a public variable, create a public property that wraps the variable, or write a public method that returns the variable. There are many options available to you, but they require you to implement *something* that is publicly available.

Comment: @Serlite Is there a different type of public method (i.e. not void) that allows me to return a public variable?

Comment: @ryemoss That sounds like exactly the solution I'm looking for.  What does that code look like?  Does it require a different type of method?

Comment: @Programmer I am not able to directly change `string` to `public string`

Comment: Why can't you directly change it it? As for ryemoss's idea to change the method return type I don't think this is a good idea because that method looks like a callback function that's being called from another script. I think this because it says `OnSomething`.....

Comment: Programmer has a good point, if this is a callback function you should not be editing the return type. Unless there is a reason you can't first declare `metaData_Content` outside of the method as as public string, you should be doing what Serlite suggested and create a new public variable, assigning it the value of metadata_content, and instead retrieve the new variable in your second script.

Comment: @Programmer When I directly change it, I get the error message `Unexpected symbol 'public'`.  And as for the second part, I agree with you.  I have tried messing around with the method and its return type and it always gives errors.  This section of code is interacting with the Vuforia Cloud Recognition Script and it seems as though there isn't much I can change.  Ideally, I'd like to keep the method as a void.  However, this doesn't solve any of my problems.

Comment: @ryemoss As said above, I agree with the first part.  The problem with declaring `metaData_Content` as a public variable outside the string is that changing the variable inside the method as no effect on the public variable outside of that method.  I've tried declaring `metaData_Content` as an empty string, but no matter what happens in the method, the variable will always be set as that empty string.  If its not clear, the method works to create a custom string based on other events in the application, `metaData_Content` is not a static string variable.

Comment: Having the variable as public outside the method, and then setting the variable in the method should work, and if it isn't changing the value, are you sure that method is getting called?

Comment: @MattL. I just retried setting the variable as public outside the method, and then setting the variable within the method when the method is called.  It did not affect the value of the public variable. Debug.Log simply returned the value of the string that is set when I declare the variable publicly outside the method.  I am sure that the method is getting called.  There is other code within the same method that is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my error by adding this line to the `SimpleCloudHandler` class:

```
public string metaData_Content;
```

and then removing the `string` type from the variable within the `OnNew SearchResult` method.  Changes shown in context here:

```
public class SimpleCloudHandler : MonoBehaviour, ICloudRecoEventHandler
{
    public string metaData_Content;

    public void OnNewSearchResult(TargetFinder.TargetSearchResult targetSearchResult)
    {
        metaData_Content = targetSearchResult.MetaData;
    }
}
```

When I previously had left the `string` type in the method, the line was creating a new local variable, rather than changing the value of the public variable.